# Convert Database data into JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I want to convert database data into JSON, but what i get by using code from this site using JavaScriptSerializer is like this

```
[{"Yes":6,"No":1,"Maybe":4}].
```

I have database table with three column named as `Yes`, `No` and `Maybe`, but I want a JSON format like:

```
[{"name":"Yes","data":6},{"name":"No","data":2},{"name":"Maybe","data":3}].
```

Means how to convert it in key:value pair in VB?

My code is :

```
Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
    Next
    rows.Add(row)
Next
json_data = serializer.Serialize(rows)
```

Comment: I get error "An item with the same key has already been added."It doesn't allow to insert data with same key again

Answer (score 1):

just change to

```
For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
    row.Add("name", col.ColumnName)
    row.Add("data", dr(col))
```

Comment: I get error "An item with the same key has already been added."It doesn't allow to insert data with same key again

Comment: but this is logical, since it is a dictionary if you have to repeat keys (something I do not understand why) just use a list of key and value - KeyValuePai

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not in the code. The problem is that the database schema is bad to begin with.

Bad:

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Yes     | No     | Maybe     |
+---------+--------+-----------+
|       6 |      2 |         4 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

Good:

```
+---------+--------+
| Name    | Data   |
+---------+--------+
| Yes     |      6 |
+---------+--------+
| No      |      2 |
+---------+--------+
| Maybe   |      4 |
+---------+--------+
```

**EDIT**

@Downvoter: suppose that you want to add a new property "Perhaps" later on.

```
+---------+--------+
| Name    | Data   |
+---------+--------+
| Yes     |      6 |
+---------+--------+
| No      |      2 |
+---------+--------+
| Maybe   |      4 |
+---------+--------+
| Perhaps |      9 |
+---------+--------+
```

How would you go about doing this in the original table?

You probably guessed it: by changing the database structure to fit the business model.

Comment: Same problem with different data or not "dummie" data should exist, perfectly valid structures on database would need different structures on business model, so I understand that change database structure to fit business model is a bad answer.

Comment: @Bardo "Perfectly valid" does not equal "Perfect". Given what we know about the problem domain, changing the table definition is the correct solution.

Comment: I think you're missing that data given by the author is obviously "dummy" data. We cannot assume just a database structure problem. The author is asking for a clearly programming problem and, without further info, I cannot assume an answer that asks him to change it's database structure as good. Sorry.

Comment: I can assume a database structure problem. Even from the dummy data, you can deduce that each column represents the same real world concept. Only the column names are different. That's a form of redundancy that should be eliminated.

Comment: Plus the fact that the author wants to use the name of a table column as a value. That should immediately trigger a red alert in your thought process.